# Multiple input of same variable in a line Python

Tags: python, variables, loops, input

I am trying to create a loop for python to create a variable of different input values.
I want to input 3 different words into the name variable. This is my code:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")  
if len(name) > 0:  
    print name
```

I want to repeat the action from the input till I stop input.

Comment: do you want to use a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of strings or [concatenate strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe (although I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking for)

```
n = 0
while n < 3:
    name = raw_input('What is your name?')
    if name:
        print name
        n + =1
```

The variable name will change each time, keep in mind.